# Permutation of list of lists of booleans in Racket

Tags: list, boolean, racket, permutation, combinatorics

I'd like to create a function that: given a natural number, returns a list of lists with all the possible values for n propositional variables.

e.g, given n = 3, it should return:

```lisp
(list  
 (list #false #false #false)  
 (list #false #false #true)  
 (list #false #true #false)  
 (list #false #true #true)  
 (list #true #false #false)  
 (list #true #false #true)  
 (list #true #true #false)  
 (list #true #true #true))
```

I know the amount of possible combinations is 2^n, but i am clueless about how to solve it on racket.

Comment: The [`cartesian-product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._cartesian-product))) function might help you, in particular `(cartesian-product '(#f #t) '(#f #t) '(#f #t))` returns the same thing as your n = 3 example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`cartesian-product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._cartesian-product))) function. `(cartesian-product (list #false #true) (list #false #true) (list #false #true))` returns the same thing as your n = 3 example. The number of copies of `(list #false #true)` in the arguments should come from n.

```
(cartesian-product (list #false #true) ...n)
```

To do this, you can use [`cartesian-product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Flist..rkt)._cartesian-product))) with `apply` to give an arbitrary number of arguments in a list, and `make-list` to make a list of N elements:

```
(define (permutation-of-lists n)
  (apply cartesian-product (make-list n (list #false #true))))
```

Using it:

```
> (permutation-of-lists 0)
(list '())
> (permutation-of-lists 1)
(list (list #false) (list #true))
> (permutation-of-lists 2)
(list (list #false #false)
      (list #false #true)
      (list #true #false)
      (list #true #true))
> (permutation-of-lists 3)
(list (list #false #false #false)
      (list #false #false #true)
      (list #false #true #false)
      (list #false #true #true)
      (list #true #false #false)
      (list #true #false #true)
      (list #true #true #false)
      (list #true #true #true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially do something like:

```lisp
(define (permutation-of-lists n)
  (if (= 1 n)
      '((#t) (#f))
      (append
        (map (λ (p) (cons #t p)) (permutation-of-lists (sub1 n)))
        (map (λ (p) (cons #f p)) (permutation-of-lists (sub1 n))))))
```

This works for any `n >= 1`. You can also optionally add a case to handle `n = 0`.
This essentially builds up these lists by appending both possible copies to the lists generated for `n - 1` - one appends `#true` and the other appends `#false` to the front (and we keep both copies).